# JavaEE changing DB schema runtime for SaaS application

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, ejb-3.0

i am developing a SaaS application by using **JavaEE** technologies (**JPA, EJB, ..**)

for multitenancy, i chose 'Shared Database, Separate Schemas' approach and designed the DB (**PostgreSQL**) like that

basically what i need to do is changing the default **schema** for user sessions in the application so that users can get their own data from the right schema

my business logic is implemented with **EJB (Container-managed)** and the app server is **glassfishv3**
so in my EJBs i am just injecting the **EntityManager** like this

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="DBNAME")
private EntityManager em;
```

and leaving the transaction management to the glassfish

i tried to write **@PostConstruct** callbacks for Stateless EJBs injecting DataSource 
but **getClientInfo**() returns null somehow so i can not even see the default schema. The reason why i injected DataSource was because i thought i have to do some low-level stuff to specify the schema.

i know if i manage the transactions in the application instead of leaving them to the app server, i can change the EntityManager values through EMF easily but i wanna keep the Container-managed infrastructure and just change some values **at runtime**

is there any way to do this with **SessionContext** or anything else ?

what is the best way of overcoming this issue ?

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand why you need to access different schemas for different users. It seems a bad design...

Comment: because every user represents a different customer and i have dedicated schemas for different customers to separate their data. Tables in the schemas are identically designed but the data is gonna be different so when they login they should see their own data through their dedicated schema.

Answer (score 1):

`@PostConstruct` is by definition the wrong way, because it is only a hint to the bean that it has been constructed and its dependencies have been injected. The bean is now in the pool of EJBs waiting for the first service call. *Then* it will be connected to the client info of that call. After that call the client info is disconnected again.

I think any kind of standard injection and standard container managed persistence stuff will not work in your case because injection is done exactly once (at EJB creation time) but your case would require injection for each service call/transaction **_AND** your injection would depend on input data - the client request containing the tenant id.

Also: I hope, you have only up to 6 (or so) tenants due to the maintenance and performance burden of that approach. I have never seen this approach *working* in the wild.

Comment: actually, i will have more than 6 tenants for sure. how is managing the transactions in the application gonna be any different in terms of performance ? because if i use EMFactory to get the EntityManager in every EJBs with some custom properties, isn't it gonna be the same that application is gonna make a DB connection before the EJB goes to the connection pool ?

Comment: The performance part is not in the application code but in the DB itself. Ask a typical DB-Guru "Should I code my application to support more smaller tables or use one bigger table?" The answer will be more or less: "IF data partioning (more tables) is really necessary, then it will be configured to be hidden inside the DB itself." The mostly cited reasoning is that even a index cached in RAM partially is more effective than several independent indices which get thrown out of RAM for every other transaction.

Comment: what would be the better SaaS way in this case then ? because i have to save customers' data and show them their own data when they login and there is just one web module running and handling the requests on a central server machine. in my application there is a lot of Stateless Beans querying the DB and i am trying to find a way of instantiating a DB connection according to the Session information like tenant_id.

Comment: The way I have seen it working several times is this: Each relevant table contains an additional `tenant_id` column. Application code then must make sure that all queries restrict the result set using that column (either in the `WHERE` clause and/or in the `JOIN` condition). Inserts and Updates must also honour that column. Bury that code in the EJB DAO layer, use code-reviews to make sure the convention is not ignored.